# Tableview crashes when I try to get images from firebase

Tags: swift, firebase

I get this error.Ive also provided a screenshot with a more detailed look at the error I've never seen this before

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Modifications to the layout engine must not be performed from a background thread after it has been accessed from the main thread.'

[image]

```
   //MARK: EXPLANATION (your passing item in down below because this allows you to call whatever is in the item class)

func generateCellForITEMS(item : Item){

    nameLabel.text = item.name

    descriptionLabel.text = item.description

    priceLabel.text = convertCurrency(item.price )

    priceLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true // this will adjust the font of the label sizse to helpt it fit even with a large price



    if item.imageLinks != nil  && item.imageLinks.count > 0 {

        downLoadImages(imageUrls: [item.imageLinks.first!]) { (images) in
            self.ItemImageView.image = images.first as? UIImage
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the UI from the main thread as the error suggests:

```
downLoadImages(imageUrls: [item.imageLinks.first!]) { (images) in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.ItemImageView.image = images.first as? UIImage
    }
}
```